# How to calculate the page load time in MVC dyanamically. I want to track each page load time in google analytics

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics

How to calculate the page load time in MVC dynamically. I want to track each page load time in Google analytic.

Comment: Google Analytics tracks this by default  (behavior/site speed; this presupposes that you have inserted the GA tracking code at the top of the page) - can you specify what you need that is not already in there ?

Comment: You can have it by checking `DOMContentLoaded` JavaScript plain event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).